# Getting a list of a class's nested classes at compile time

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I want to get a *list*, so to speak, of the nested classes of some class, which can then be used as input to the parameter pack for another class.

For example, here is the class that would contain the nested types:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    class FirstNested
    {
        // ...
    }

    class SecondNested
    {
        // ...
    }

}
```

and here is the class with the parameter pack that would use the nested types:

```
template <class...Ts>
class UsesFooNestedTypes
{
private:
    std::variant<Ts...> _variantOfFooNestedTypes;  // irrelevant, just an exmaple of what might be done with the types.
}
```

is there any way to do this, or something similar?

```
UsesFooNestedTypes<get_nested_types_of<Foo>> fooNestedTypesUser;
```

Edit: Upon giving it some thought, I’ve realised that this question doesn’t reflect my actual problem closely enough. So, I have created a more specific question here: [Automatically get nested state classes to use in std::variant variadic parameter for state pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71807889/automatically-get-nested-state-classes-to-use-in-stdvariant-variadic-parameter)

Comment: What's the problem you actually want to solve that way? There's no such feature AFAIK.

Comment: There might be a way to do it if every such class contains a macro or inherits from a CRTP base class. But it's only marginally better than manually maintaining the list of types.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm trying to implement state pattern using a std::variant, with the declarations for the individual state classes all nested within a single class. I want to at compile time automatically create a variant with all the nested state classes.

Comment: _@user18754779_ I agree with @holy here. CRTP is the way to go. Though realizing that using nested classes just makes it harder, and will be worse to extend later without changing the core declarations.

Comment: @user18754779 I would make the state-machine class a template, with the states as a variadic template parameter.

Comment: Old, unmaintained, and partially quirky, but still a source of inspiration maybe ;-): https://github.com/makulik/sttcl

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not really seeing a helpful application of CRTP in this case. Maybe combined with that bizarre trick giving a macro that evaluates to a different number every time.

Answer (score 3):

Directly getting the types of all nested classes of a specific class requires the support of reflection, which is currently impossible in C++.

If you can modify `Foo`, then you can define a member type and use a `tuple` to store all nested classes of `Foo`

```
class Foo {
 public:
  class FirstNested { };
  class SecondNested { };
  // ...
  using NestedClasses = std::tuple<FirstNested, SecondNested, ...>;
};
```

Then use some meta-programming tricks to get the types of these nested classes and instantiate `std::variant`

```
template <class Tuple>
class UsesFooNestedTypes;

template <class... Ts>
class UsesFooNestedTypes<std::tuple<Ts...>> {
 private:
  std::variant<Ts...> _variantOfFooNestedTypes;
};

int main() {
  UsesFooNestedTypes<Foo::NestedClasses> fooNestedTypesUser;
}
```