# Automatically get nested state classes to use in std::variant variadic parameter for state pattern

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

My problem is this: I have a class which stores a std::variant of state classes (state pattern). The states themselves are private nested classes of the class which owns this std::variant.

```
class Foo
{
private:
    class OnState
    {
        // …
    }

    class OffState
    {
        // …
    }

    std::variant<StatesTs…> m_state;
}
```

I want to at, compile time, give all the nested state classes to the variadic parameter of the std::variant, without having to manually maintain a list of state types. I want to be able to create a new nested state class and have it automatically become a parameter to the std::variant’s parameter pack.

Thus far, I have identified that this might be able to be solved using the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern, although forgive me for my knowledge on this pattern and it’s capabilities is very limited.

Comment: That's called static reflection and it's not possible.

Comment: I don't think it's any different from your previous question.

Comment: @PasserBy Hm. Well is there no way to put some code before or after each state class definition so the compiler automatically adds each state class to a list of parameters?

Comment: At that point you might as well just type out all the types.